# Dustjs - Loop iteration as ___

Tags: dust.js

In my Models, variables share identical names, like `name`, or `slug`. This causes a problem, because I loop through one, and in each iteration, I loop through the other model, but in the inner loop, when I use `{slug}` I cannot access the 'parent" slug.

I've solved this by creating a new scope immediately after I start a loop, and put a parameter in it to name the iteration, like so:

```
{#categories}{#. category=.}
    <section class="category {category.slug}">
        <h2 class="name">
            <a href="/{category.slug}">
                {category.name}
            </a>
        </h2>
        {#category.forums}{#. forum=.}
            <article class="forum {forum.slug}">
                <h3 class="name">
                    <a href="/{category.slug}/{forum.slug}">
                        {forum.name}
                    </a>
                </h3>
                <p class="description">
                    {forum.description}
                </p>
            </article>
        {/.}{/category.forums}
    </section>
{/.}{/categories}
```

Since this works, what my question is, is, "**How can I name the iteration in the same tag that starts the loop?**" `{#categories category=.}` does not work.

I can live with what I've got, but I'm trying to clean it up as much as possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're on the right track. Instead of passing the current context as a parameter, pass the previous context instead.

```
{#categories}
    <section class="category {slug}">
        <h2 class="name">
            <a href="/{slug}">
                {name}
            </a>
        </h2>
        {#forums category=.}
            <article class="forum {slug}">
                <h3 class="name">
                    <a href="/{category.slug}/{slug}">
                        {name}
                    </a>
                </h3> 
                <p class="description">
                    {description}
                </p>
            </article>
        {/forums}
    </section>
{/categories}
```

Comment: You know, I actually did this first. Is this really the best way to do it?

Comment: It doesn't really get any simpler! You're always using the current scope in an unqualified fashion, and passing in a parent's scope.

Comment: Alright. I just switched to dust from ejs, so its just a bit to get used to.